# How to find debug information for Ubuntu unlock screen

Tags: ubuntu, lockscreen, gnome-3

running stock Ubuntu 17.10, gnome shell, razer blade stealth laptop.

after suspend / laptop lid closed, whenever I try to unlock the device, I get past the password check, the screen flashes black, and I'm back to the main login screen (not unlock)

upon second login, th so I can debug / submit errorse desktop session is lost and it behaves as a fresh login event.

looking at Syslog there is no crash / error info that's useful, or related, so I'm not certain where to surface data to further debug / submit bugs to the issue tracker.

thanks!

Comment: I have this exact issue. I believe it has something to do with the suspending - I turned off suspending on my system and I haven't had any issues with it since. But I would really like to find a real solution to the problem as not having suspend drains my battery quite fast.